# How to use a variable string to reference an existing object name on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have an access 2007 form with 18 textbox controls in two columns.  They are to add colors and color codes to a vendor table when entering a new style.
Column one's controls are named Color1, Color2, etc, and column two's controls are named Code1, Code2, etc.

The code below goes through the textbox controls on the form and gets the control's name and value fine.

I do realize I'll need to put another if/then type statement to only perform the actions if the control selected by the case statement has a name beginning with "color".  I'll add that later.

If you see the sql statement, I'm trying to insert a new color/code combination by calling up the control with the name beginning with "code" and ending with the number associated with the "color" textbox currently being evaluated in the case select.
TL;DR, when textbox "color1" is being evaluated, I want the value of what is in "code1" to be a part of the sql statement as well.  The number at the end is the link between the two.

I'm sure I'm probably using an incorrect reference for ctrlcode or something like that, but if someone knows what I'm trying to do and could help me get this working, I'd appreciate it.

```
Dim sql As String, ctrlcode As Control  'Also tried as Object

For Each ctl In Me.Controls
Select Case ctl.ControlType
Case acTextBox           'Only searching textboxes
    'Debug.Print ctl.Name, ctl.Value
    If Not IsNull(ctl.Value) Then
        Debug.Print ctl.Name, ctl.Value, Right(ctl.Name, 1)
        **Next line fails   Runtime error 424, object required**
        Set ctrlcode = frm.Controls("code" & Right(ctl.Name, 1))
        Debug.Print ctrlcode.Value, "ctrlcode value"

        sql = "INSERT INTO tblVendorColors (Stylecode, color, colorcode, coloravail)" _
            & " VALUES (Styletext, '" & ctl.Value & "', '" & ctrlcode.value & "', true)"
    Debug.Print sql
    End If

Case Else
    ' pass
End Select
```

Next

Comment: Styletext is the name of the form control textbox ( rather than "text1") containing the style name.

Answer (score 4):

Use `For i = 1 To 9` to loop through your text box pairs.  Then you can reference the text box values as `Me.Controls("Color" & i).Value` and  `Me.Controls("Code" & i).Value`

Instead of building and executing an `INSERT`, you can add a row to a recordset and store the values there.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Long

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblVendorColors", dbAppendOnly)
With rs
    For i = 1 To 9
        If Not IsNull(Me.Controls("Color" & i).Value) Then
            .AddNew
            !Stylecode.Value = Me!Styletext.Value
            !Color.Value = Me.Controls("Color" & i).Value
            !colorcode.Value = Me.Controls("Code" & i).Value
            !coloravail.Value = True
            .Update
        End If
    Next
    .Close
End With
```

Comment: +1 That's a lot cleaner. But I wonder: why do you use `.Value` (on both sides of the assignment)? Force of habit, or does it solve a problem that could come up when relying on `.Value` being the default property of recordset fields and controls?

Comment: My preference is to explicitly include `.Value` when I want `.Value`.  It's not really a benefit here, but doesn't cause harm either.  ;-)  I find it a useful habit because I'm already prepared for situations where the default property is not what's referenced ... for example `TypeName(!Color)` would return *"Field2"* instead of the field's `.Value`

Comment: I love both code answers here.  In hindsight, going with the for loop would be cleaner and if building it to more than 9 boxes a for loop avoids having to do more manipulation in finding the number in the text string of the control name.  

I could also rename the single digit boxes to 01 through 09 then 10 and up.. etc, but even still, the code would just get bloated without need going through the each ctl method.   

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2):

```
    **Next line fails   Runtime error 424, object required**
    Set ctrlcode = frm.Controls("code" & Right(ctl.Name, 1))
```

Instead of `frm.`, use `Me.`.

You should put `Option Explicit` at the start of all modules, and set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor. This forces you to `Dim` all variables and find such errors already at compile time.

In addition, if `Styletext` is a control, you need to treat it as `ctl` and `ctrlcode` when building your SQL string.

```
" VALUES ('" & Me.Styletext & "', '" & ctl.Value ...
```

Comment: Thanks Andre.  I did already fix up my Styletext part (thanks for the reminder) and it is the exact answer I was looking for.  I'm surprised it was that close... me vs frm.    Good call on the explicit/require declarations.

That being said, I'll probably go with a for loop like Hans has up there.    I was originally going to avoid that type in case I built up the form options at some point, but with the need to check for "color" vs "code"  on each box, it now seems less efficient.  And changing the number in the for declaration isn't all that hard if I make changes.